# Setting gRPC Java

Tags: grpc-java

Good day to you Java and gRPC gurus out there.

I have been following this https://github.com/jpdna/gRPC-maven-helloworld, because I am learning gRPC using Java.

I was able to compile it using mvn clean package.
But when I loaded the project in Eclipse, the file:

```
org.jpdna.grpchello.HelloWorldServer
```

is looking for the class "`GreeterGrpc`".

I tried executing this in the terminal:

```
$ protoc --java_out=/gRPC-maven-helloworld/src/main/java hello_world.proto
```

It generated the following classes:

```
  - HelloRequest.java
  - HelloRequestOrBuilder.java
  - HelloResponse.java
  - HelloResponseOrBuilder.java
  - HelloWorldProto.java
```

But no GreeterGrpc.java which is defined as a service in this project.
If you don't mind me asking, I would like to know how to create or generate this GreeterGrpc.java class?

Many thanks to you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `protoc` plugin `protoc-gen-grpc-java` to generate `GreeterGrpc.class` when complie `hello_world.proto`.

Or you can use a maven plugin to achieve the same thing. 
My maven config:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>


<extension>
    <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
</extension>


<plugin>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>uncompress</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <executable>${basedir}/bin/upgrade.sh ${environment}</executable>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>


<plugin>
    <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
<protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.1.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
        <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
        <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.0.3:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>compile-custom</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @Z fp, thank you for taking time to answer. But I guess I found the answer to my question. You can find it below. Thanks =)!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my question... the solution is just to right click on the project on Eclipse, then choose Run As --> Maven generate-sources. Once the source codes and its folders are generated in the target folder. Right click on those generated folders (with source codes) then, Build Path --> Use as Source Folder. The error will go away since it will be able to resolve the missing classes.

Thanks and have a good day =)!